# Error when copying code for mapbox navigation app tutorial

Tags: android

Current route gives me an error saying:

```
required Error:(50, 71) error: 
    incompatible types: 
    com.mapbox.services.api.directions.v5.models.DirectionsRoute cannot be 
    converted to com.mapbox.api.directions.v5.models.DirectionsRoute
```

However when I fix this error, `navigationMapRoute.addRoute(currentRoute)` gives me an error:

```
Error:(58, 53) error: incompatible types: com.mapbox.services.api.directions.v5.models.DirectionsRoute cannot be converted to com.mapbox.api.directions.v5.models.DirectionsRoute
```

And vice versa:

```
currentRoute = response.body().getRoutes().get(0);
navigationMapRoute.addRoute(currentRoute);
```

Comment: past your complete code

Comment: It appears that the API has two classes named `DirectionsRoute`. You have to ensure that you are using the correct one.

Comment: For tips on creating a good code example, please read [mcve].